# Connect android application to MYSQL database

Tags: android, mysql

When i try to connect android application to MYSQL database server the following errors occurs.i am using android studio in linux mint:

> 05-10 10:46:58.555 29599-29599/com.example.pc.hms_treva  D/Atlas:
>   Validating map...  05-10 10:46:58.660
>   29599-29619/com.example.pc.hms_treva I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized
>   EGL, version 1.4  05-10 10:46:58.743
>   29599-29619/com.example.pc.hms_treva D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug
>   mode 0 05-10 10:46:58.787 29599-29619/com.example.pc.hms_treva
>   W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented  05-10 10:46:58.787
>   29599-29619/com.example.pc.hms_treva W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf0355c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Here is code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView prev, now, next;
TextView display, bottom;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previmg);
    now = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.token);
    next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nextimg);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    bottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tokennum);

    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Connect runner = new Connect();
            //  String sleepTime = time.getText().toString();
            runner.execute();
        }
    });
    now.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StatusUpdate.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}


class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    MainActivity m = new MainActivity();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String username = "qqq";
        String password = "dddd";
        Connection DbConn = null;
        try {
            DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.x:1433/DATABASE NAME;user=" + username + ";password=" + password);
            Log.i("Connection","open");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"coonnected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.w("Connection", "open");
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = DbConn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        ResultSet reset = null;
        try {
            reset = stmt.executeQuery(" select TOKENID from DEPTVISIT where DEPVISITID=1 ");
            display.setText(reset.getString(1));
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            DbConn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: In Which version you are trying to run. `Kitkat` or `Lollipop`.

Comment: the above error is not related with DB, you can ignore it, it has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Lollipop 5.1  database is not MySQL ,it is Microsoft SQL server

Comment: @shriduttkothari i got error like this   failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system   what it means

Comment: @user6313452 chmod error comes when you try to modify any file on the system partition as in android we don't have authority to edit system files,

Comment: @user6313452 btw, you should be getting some other errors also, as above two errors you mentioned are not exactly your problem, so share complete logs so i can help you more.

Comment: @shriduttkothari thank you for ur advice .currently its working finely..

Comment: @user6313452, what did you do to fix, please post in answer so any other with same issue can get help from this post.

Answer (score 0):

[AsyncTask in android developer manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

You should write the code in doInBackground() instead of onPreExecute()
because onPreExecute() is executed on UI thread and useful for declarations or creating a progress dialog

Write the code which takes long computational time inside doInBackground() such as database query or parsing the ResultSet or JSON etc.

To connect android to mysql 
download the mysql jar from mysql and then import it as a jar module in your project
or you can add a dependency from gradle

then you can directly use the following method to connect to database

```
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String method=params[0];
            if(method.equals("register"))
            {
                String username=params[1];
                String password=params[2];

         try {       
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.100:3306/dbname","username","password");

             Log.d("DB", "Connection succesfull");
             Log.d("DB","param1"+username);
             Log.d("DB","param2"+password);
             PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement("insert       into registertest values(?,?)");

             pst.setString(1,username);
             pst.setString(2,password);

             int x = pst.executeUpdate();
             connection.close();

             Log.d("DB",x + "record inserted");
             connection.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e1) {
              String trace=e1.getStackTrace().toString();
              Log.d("DB", "SQL Exception"+trace,e1);
         }

     }

    return null;
}
```